# explosive force equivalent

Tags: space-shuttle, rocket-explosion

i've seen 1 link that would direct me to a site that gave an equivalent of what would happen if a SATURN 5 let go on the pad, but not the Shuttle, was wondering what the force equivalent would be if the Shuttle would have exploded on the pad (SRB's, external tank, and the Shuttle itself lettin go all at once)

Comment: That depends mostly on whether the SRBs would explode. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonium_perchlorate can explode, but in the SRBs it's in a form that resists explosion quite well...

Comment: i"ve heard some say the force of a "small" nuclear weapon, but they may just be guessing

Comment: Since most, if not all, mechanical energy of the orbiter come from chemical combustion, you should be able to estimate a lower bound by calculate it.

Comment: @RickJensen: Note that "small nuclear weapon" goes all the way down to ["10-20 tonnes TNT equivalent"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davy_Crockett_(nuclear_device)).

Answer (score 5):

Partial answer:

Volume 2 of a March 1981 study (links below) by the DOD gives the External Tank explosive force on the pad as equivalent to 54,000 pounds of TNT.

[image]

Rationale for the calculation is described in the paper.

If you want to read some *interesting* predictions about what would have happened if one SRB came off during first stage, etc, etc, these papers are for you.

SPACE SHUTTLE RANGE SAFETY COMMAND DESTRUCT SYSTEM ANALYSIS AND VERIFICATION

- [PHASE I - DESTRUCT SYSTEM ANALYSIS AND VERIFICATION](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a103453.pdf)
- [PHASE II - ORDNANCE OPTIONS FOR A SPACE SHUTTLE RANGE SAFETY COMMAND
  DESTRUCT SYSTEM](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a102320.pdf)
- [PHASE III -BREAKUP OF SPACE SHUTTLE CLUSTER VIA RANGE SAFETY COMMAND
  DESTRUCT SYSTEM](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a103530.pdf)

Comment: These are very cool!